# PigLatin C++ function

Tags: c++, string, function

This code is giving me a lot of strange errors. For whatever reason, the "newstring" function is not running. I think it may have something to do with the fact that it is part of a cout statement, because if I remember correctly, it does not give the same error if I call the function independently of the cout statement. The program requires a string function, but the new function is not running for some reason. Could anyone take a look at the code?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    void newstring(string);
    bool isVowel(char ch);
    string rotate(string pStr);
    string pigLatinString(string pStr);

    int main()
    {
        string str;

        cout << "Enter a sentence to be translated to Pig Latin: ";
        getline(cin, str);
        cout << endl;

        cout << "The pig Latin form of " << str << " is: " << newstring(str);

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;

    }

    bool isVowel(char ch)
    {
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
            case 'Y':
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            case 'y':
                return true;
            default: 
                return false;
        }
    }
    string rotate(string pStr)
    {
        string::size_type len = pStr.length();
        string rStr;
        rStr = pStr.substr(1, len - 1) + pStr[0];
        return rStr;
    }       
    string pigLatinString(string pStr)
    {
        string :: size_type len;
        bool foundVowel;
        if (isVowel(pStr[0]))
            pStr = pStr + "-way";
        else 
            {
                pStr = pStr + '-';
                pStr = rotate(pStr);
                len = pStr.length();
                foundVowel = false;

            for ( int counter = 1; counter < len - 1; counter++)
                {
                      if (isVowel(pStr[0]))
                {
                    foundVowel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else 
                    pStr = rotate(pStr);

                if (!foundVowel)
                    pStr = pStr.substr(1, len) + "-way";
                    else    
                    pStr = pStr + "ay";
                }
                return pStr;
            }
    }

    string newstring(string sentence)
    {   
        string newsentence, currentword;

        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            if (sentence[i]==' ')
            {
                pigLatinString(currentword)+" ";
                currentword.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                currentword+=sentence[i];
            }
        }
        return newsentence;
    }
```

Comment: @Cory, Does my answer helped fixing you issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your `newstring` prototype is wrong.

```
void newstring(string);
```

Should be

```
string newstring(string);
```

Comment: I think that was part of the problem. It's still not working correctly.

Comment: What is not working..? I could compile it successfully. You you have any new error or run time issue?

Answer (score 0):

Function newstring is declared as having type void

```
void newstring(string);
```

You may not create objects of type void and send them in an output stream

```
cout << "The pig Latin form of " << str << " is: " << newstring(str);
```

Also the function has no definition because you defined another function with the same name but returning std::string

```
string newstring(string sentence)
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pigLatinString(currentword)+" ";
```

pigLatinString returns a string, but you don't do anything with that result.

newstring returns newsentence, but is is empty.

Maybe you should fill newsentence with what is returned from pigLatinString?

Oh, and now I notice you have two `newstring`s... a void and a string...